# get collection from client in meteor/node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to get a collection from client using meteor.

From client:

```js
   Template.mapBody.onCreated(function() {
        var date = this.subscribe("friendUsers");
        for (x in date) {
            console.log(x);
        }
    });
```

From server:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish("friendUsers", getFriendUsers);

    function getFriendUsers() {
        return Ski_Stations.find(); 
    }
}
```

I get nothing in the console. Does some one have any ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the meteor documentation - Meteor.subscribe returns a subscription handle, which is great for stopping or seeing if the subscription is ready.  But I'm not sure this is what you want in this case.  I think you are going to want to iterate the collection like this..

```
var friendCursor = friendUsers.find();
var friend;
while ( friendCursor.hasNext() ) {
   friend = friendCursor.next();
   console.log( friend.somefieldhere );
}
```

Comment: is correct, a subscription returns a *subscription handle* which is not a collection of documents that you can iterate over. You have to `.find()` on the collection to get a *cursor* which is iterable.